# Como recuperar o valor do scroll apenas ida

Tags: javascript

Fiquei sem ideia para o titulo, mas a pergunta seria como poderia recuperar o valor do scroll, porem somente a ida e não a volta. Exemplo:
digamos que o usuario deu scroll e o valor está em 600 porem ele voltou, eu queria não recuperar esse valor da volta. Tipo 599, 598, 597... ou seja recuperar apenas 601, 602, 603 e etc.

```js
onscroll = ()=>{
console.log(this.scrollY)
}

document.body.style.height = "2000px";
```

Obs: se alguem tiver alguma ideia para o titulo melhor. So falar que altero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defina uma variavel fora do `window.onscroll`, e então faça um instrução aonde quando o valor do window.scroll for maior que o valor da variavel a terá o valor do window.scroll.

```js
var scrollSalvo = 0;

onscroll = () => {
    if (this.scrollY > scrollSalvo) {
        scrollSalvo = this.scrollY;
        console.clear()
        console.log(this.scrollY /*ou scrollSalvo*/)
    }
}

document.body.style.height = "2000px";
```

Comment: +1 Me atrevi em colocar um `console.clear()` apenas para facilitar a visualização :)